# Why localhost displays nothing after creating a virtual host?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I'm learning Laravel PHP. So I followed a tutorial on YouTube about creating a virtual host for XAMPP Apache server and I tried to modify httpd-vhosts.conf file in XAMPP/apache/conf/extra. My project directory is "D:\Applications\XAMPP\htdocs\www\EpsilonProgram" so how do I set the DocumentRoot in httpd-vhosts.conf? If I set as

```
DocumentRoot "D:\Applications\XAMPP\htdocs\www\EpsilonProgram"
```

and then turn on XAMPP Apache server and run

```
http://localhost/
```

, it always displays

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.0.8 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Please help!

Comment: Because the `public` folder inside your Laravel project should be your DocumentRoot

Comment: You should have 2 VHOST 1) locahost and 2) your new project. Would have been useful to show us the Mods you made to the httpd-vhosts.conf file

Comment: have you copied the ```.htaccess``` file from "public" folder to the root folder of your project? Please try this!

Comment: @RamishaMukhtar I would not recommend at all using the root of your project as DocumentRoot. Laravel uses the public folder for a reason, so no other files except those in the public folder are exposed. If you use the root of your project as DocumentRoot your `.env` file and containing secrets/passwords might be exposed

Comment: @brombeer so for this reason we must set the ```public``` folder as root of the project. But as far as we're running the project on localhost, isn't that approach safe, i.e. copying ```.htaccess``` file to root of project?

Comment: @RamishaMukhtar It might be "secure" when running on localhost, but I doubt it would work. The `.htaccess` from the `public` folder refers to a file `index.php` which isn't present in the root of a project. And why hassle with all that when you could just set the correct DocumentRoot?!

Comment: @brombeer So you mean change into this will resolve the solution? 
DocumentRoot "D:\Applications\XAMPP\htdocs\www\EpsilonProgram\public"

Comment: @brombeer you can rename the ```server.php``` to ```index.php```. It always works for me!

Comment: @F.B.IAgent That _should_ work if everything else is set up correct, we only see what you posted here.

Comment: @RamishaMukhtar Glad it works for you. Setting the DocumentRoot to the `public` folder has always worked for me. And I don't need to fiddle around/rename files back when deploying an app

Comment: @brombeer Glad you do so but I usually don't bother in configuring the local server and access the project locally on browser using the link generated by ```php artisan serve``` on git bash.

Comment: @RamishaMukhtar Sure, that works too (reliably when only having one project, a little too much tinkering when you need more projects running that depend on each other). But OPs question is specifically about using Vhosts with Apache.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. It worked!